# PHP JSON data missing after decoding from api

Tags: php, json, guzzle

I am getting data using guzzle http GET call. It retrieves the data fine and I know that all the data is retrieved. However, when I try to get data from child object/array after decoding the body I get NULL response with no errors. Below is my code.

```
$data = $res->getBody(); 
$dataTwo = json_decode($data);
var_dump($dataTwo->appeal->askAmounts); // this returns NULL 
var_dump($dataTwo->appeal); // this returns the below
```

```
object(stdClass)[3388]
  public 'appealVersionCode' => string '96603' (length=5)
  public 'appeal' => 
    object(stdClass)[3390]
      public 'key' => string '656404' (length=6)
      public 'description' => string '656404' (length=6)
      public 'outreach' => 
        object(stdClass)[3403]
          public 'key' => string 'Data Information' (length=6)
          public 'name' => string 'Data Information' (length=15)
          public 'description' => string 'Data Information' (length=15)
          public 'longDescription' => null
          public 'imagePath' => string 'Data Information' (length=21)
          public 'thumbnailPath' => string 'Data Information' (length=21)
          public 'url' => null
          public 'askAmounts' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
      public 'askAmounts' => 
        array (size=5)
          0 => 
            object(stdClass)[3394]
              ...
          1 => 
            object(stdClass)[3400]
              ...
          2 => 
            object(stdClass)[3401]
              ...
          3 => 
            object(stdClass)[3404]
              ...
          4 => 
            object(stdClass)[3389]
              ...
  public 'description' => string 'Data Information' (length=20)
  public 'name' => string 'Data Information' (length=20)
  public 'products' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string '38621' (length=5)
```

I know that the data is there because I can do the following:

```
$data = $res->getBody->getContents(); // Which outputs below 
,"url":null,"askAmounts":[]},"askAmounts":[{"amount":10,"impact":null},{"amount":25,"impact":null},{"amount":50,"impact":null},{"amount":75,"impact":null},{"amount":100,"impact":null}]},"description":
```

Comment: If your dump is `$dataTwo->appeal`, then it is `$dataTwo->appeal->appeal->askAmounts`.

Comment: Yes. Here I am spending hours trying to solve this and you step in and solve it like it aint no thang. I envy you.

Thanks good sir.

Answer (score 0):

As Markus Zeller so politely commented. It is two appeals deep.

```
$dataTwo->appeal->appeal->askAmounts.
```